# Directline with Polyfill ES5 in IE

Tags: javascript, html, chatbot, web-chat

I am currently having an issue with the botchat framework from Microsoft.

In essence, they are saying that for the framework to work in I.E., all you have to do is change the script for their webchat-es5.js version. However, this still does not work at all in IE. I am using IE 11. All other browsers work fine, except IE.

Could someone please point me in the right direction so that I may have this ChatBot actually work in IE?

Here is the code I am using for all of this stuff:

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="webchat" role="main" style="position: absolutel bottom:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-es5.js"></script>
```

Relevant JavaScript:

```
 const styleOptions =
    {
        accent: '#0063B1',
        backgroundColor: 'White; border:2px solid #23447e; border-radius: 25px; padding-top:20px',
        cardEmphasisBackgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
        paddingRegular: 10,
        paddingWide: 10 * 2,
        subtle: '#767676',
        bubbleBackground: '#CCCCCC',
        bubbleBorder: 'solid 1px #E6E6E6',
        bubbleBorderRadius: 10,
        bubbleFromUserBackground: '#0084ff',
        bubbleFromUserBorder: 'solid 1px #E6E6E6',
        bubbleFromUserBorderRadius: 10,
        bubbleFromUserTextColor: 'White',
        bubbleImageHeight: 100, //240,
        bubbleMaxWidth: 480, // screen width = 600px
        bubbleMinHeight: 40,
        bubbleMinWidth: 250, // min screen width = 300px, Edge requires 372px (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/13621468/)
        bubbleTextColor: 'Black',
        // Send box
        hideSendBox: false,
        hideUploadButton: false,
        microphoneButtonColorOnDictate: '#F33',
        sendBoxBackground: 'White',
        sendBoxButtonColor: '#767676',
        sendBoxButtonColorOnDisabled: '#CCC',
        sendBoxButtonColorOnFocus: '#333',
        sendBoxButtonColorOnHover: '#333',
        sendBoxHeight: 40,
        sendBoxMaxHeight: 200,
        sendBoxTextColor: 'Black',
        sendBoxBorderBottom: '',
        sendBoxBorderLeft: '2px solid #23447e; border-radius: 25px',
        sendBoxBorderRight: '2px solid #23447e; border-radius: 25px',
        sendBoxBorderTop: '2px solid #23447e; border-radius: 25px',
        sendBoxPlaceholderColor: '#23447e',
        sendBoxTextWrap: false,
        typingAnimationBackgroundImage: 'https://support.signal.org/hc/article_attachments/360016877511/typing-animation-3x.gif',
        spinnerAnimationBackgroundImage: 'https://support.signal.org/hc/article_attachments/360016877511/typing-animation-3x.gif',
        avatarSize: 80,
        botAvatarImage: 'https://s3.gifyu.com/images/oie_3BXuLVEkv2Ad.gif',
        userAvatarImage: 'https://i.ibb.co/5xz4X4P/kissclipart-generic-person-icon-clipart-computer-icons-person-96a092499db1d0d3.png',
        botAvatarInitials: '',
        userAvatarInitials: ''
    };

const token = 'MY TOKEN SECRET IS HERE';

const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
        dispatch({
            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
            payload: {
                name: 'webchat/join',
                value: { language: window.navigator.language }
            }
        });
    }
    return next(action);
});



window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
    styleOptions
}, document.getElementById("webchat"));
```

I've also tried their other version of rendering/creating the webchat :

```
window.fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' })
.then(function (res) {
  return res.json();
})
.then(function (json) {
  const token = json.token;
  window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
      token: token
    })
  }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
  document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
});
```

With this instantiated version, it still doesn't work in IE, and in other browsers, it loads the MockBot from GitHub instead of my own chatbot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions in IE11 are not supported, so you store middleware is causing the problem. Take a look at the code snippet below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Web Chat: Full-featured bundle with ES5 polyfills</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--
      This CDN points to the latest official release of Web Chat. If you need to test against Web Chat's latest bits, please refer to pointing to Web Chat's MyGet feed:
      https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#how-to-test-with-web-chats-latest-bits
    -->
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-es5.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100% }
      body { margin: 0 }

      #webchat {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script>

      // This code is modified to run in browser without async and Promise support
      window.fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' })
        .then(function (res) {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then(function (json) {
          const token = json.token;

          const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
            {}, 
            function(store) {
              return function(next) {
                return function(action) {
                  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                    store.dispatch({
                        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: 'webchat/join',
                            value: { language: window.navigator.language }
                        }
                    });
                  }
                  return next(action);
                }
              }
            }
          );

          window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
            directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
              token: token
            }),
            store: store
          }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

          document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok sorry for the many comments.. i have narrowed things down a bit... basically, I am loading my webchat through a separate script file... this seems to be the real issue right now (for some reason) ? If the script code is directly inside the HTML page it works perfectly, yet if i store it in a "LoadWebChat.js" script and call the script file, it stops working in IE?

Comment: I have accepted this answer since it did let me run this in IE... the main reason why this was not working is that IE does not support a LOT of features of javascript, to name one: optional parameters in function declarations, etc... so to make this work we would have had to completely change everything about our Chatbot... Instead, we are redirecting users to use Chrome. Sad though, this is a Microsoft driven framework, and it has issues working with their own browser...

Comment: Web Chat imports multiple polyfils to support IE11 in their [ES5 Bundle](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/bundle/src/index-es5.ts). If they are missing one, I would recommend opening an issue in their [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/).